# Using lxml, what causes a "lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Document is empty" error?

Tags: python, xml, mechanize, lxml

I'm using mechanize/cookiejar/lxml to read a page and it works for some but not others. The error I'm getting in them is the one in the title. I can't post the pages here because they aren't SFW, but is there a way to fix it? Basically, this is what I do:

```
import mechanize, cookielib
from lxml import etree    

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(False)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 maverick Firefox/3.6.13')]

response = br.open('...')
tree = etree.parse(response) #error
```

After that I get the root and search the document for the values I want. Apparently iterparse doesn't crash it, but at the moment I'm assuming it doesn't just because I didn't process anything with it. Plus, I haven't figured out yet how to search for the stuff with it.

I've tried disabling gzip and enabling sending the referer as well but neither solves the problem. I also tried saving the sourcecode to the disk and creating the tree from there just for the sake of it and I get the same error.

**edit**
The response I get seems to be fine, using print repr(response) as suggested I get a `<response_seek_wrapper at 0xa4a160c whose wrapped object = <stupid_gzip_wrapper at 0xa49acec whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0xa49c32c>>>`. I can also save the response using the read() method and check that the saved .xml works on the browser and everything.

Also, in one of the pages, there is a `&rsquo;` that gives me the following error: "lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'rsquo' not defined, line 17, column 7054". So far I've replaced it with a regex, but is there a parser that can handle this? I've gotten this error even with the lxml.html.parse suggested below.

Regarding the file being highlighted, I meant that when I open it with gEdit it does this kinda: http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/9574/gedit.jpg

Comment: Have you tried writing the xml to a file, then you can study it and process it with just xml and maybe get a clearer idea . For debugging lxml issues we would need to see the xml

Comment: Have you tried something like `print repr(response)` just before the failing statement? Does it like an empty XML document? Does it look like an XML document at all?

Comment: @Mark I am not very good at xml however. I did open it with gEdit and some parts of it were outlined red, which I think means that the xml is broken though my browser (Firefox) has no problem with it. If that's the case I guess there isn't a lot I can do besides using another library or changing the way I process the file? I initially thought about using regex instead but went for an XML parser since that seemed to be the right thing to do, though at this point I guess I'll have to go back to regex...

Comment: @John Machin yes print repr(response) prints something, and i can also save it with response.read() to a .xml file directly from the code just before the error. The problem seems to be parsing the page.

Comment: @wakawaka: Please try to answer the "does it look like" questions. Edit your question to add extra information, don't leave comments scattered around.

Comment: @John Machin Sorry. It doesn't look like an empty xml. The print repr says `<response_seek_wrapper at 0xa4a160c whose wrapped object = <stupid_gzip_wrapper at 0xa49acec whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0xa49c32c>>>`. Like I said I could save the contents of the response to a .xml file and it worked fine so the response was ok.

Comment: @wakawaka - in response to me you said there were parts outlined but to @John you said it works - please show us the xml -which you have in the file - also edit your question not add comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use lxml.html.parse for html it can handle even very broken html, you still get an error then?

Comment: I still can't get the `&rsquo;` to be parsed correctly without replacing it, but this solves the initial problem I had. Thanks.

Comment: works or me: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/318174/ or you want » instead of &#8217; ?

Comment: Basically you are not getting XML back from the response but html

Comment: thanks! finally a solution for parsing some custom xml files!

Answer (score 1):

What is the nature of `response`? According to the help, etree.parse is expecting one of:

```
   - a file name/path
   - a file object
   - a file-like object
   - a URL using the HTTP or FTP protocol
```